# How to use Postgresql DISTINCT ON in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I am using DISTINCT ON to fetch latest rows from two joined tables. In my case a subscriber belongs to many categories and I need to fetch the latest category a subscriber belongs to. I've got it working in raw query but I need to recreate it using Eloquent.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (subscribers.id) subscribers.*, 
subscriber_categories.* 
FROM subscribers 
LEFT JOIN subscriber_categories
  ON subscribers.id = subscriber_categories.subscriber_id 
ORDER BY subscribers.id, subscriber_categories.created_at DESC;
```

I have tried the following but not working. It's fetching all records from both tables:

```
Subscribers::
   ->join('subscriber_categories', 'subscribers.id', '=', 'subscriber_categories.subscriber_id')
   ->distinct('subscribers.id')
   ->latest('subscribers.id', subscriber_categories.created_at)
   ->paginate(7);
```

Comment: In laravel `distinct()` does not accepts any argument: https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/queries#selects it just add `SELECT DISTINCT` so it is a distinct an all selected fields. In your case it does nothing because each Subscriber is distinct from others almost for the primary key. You can debug your query by adding ->toSql().

Comment: yeah, i was going for ->toSql() as well.

Comment: Ok, after that you debugged your query you can always ask here with further details if you need. You can always edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up doing this. (totally abandoned  DISTINCT ON):

```
     $subscribers = \DB::table('subscribers AS t1')
        ->leftJoin(\DB::raw('(SELECT * FROM subscriber_categories A WHERE id in (SELECT MAX(id) FROM subscriber_categories group by subscriber_id)) AS t2'), function($join) {
        $join->on('t1.id', '=', 't2.subscriber_id');
            })->select('t1.id', 't1.s_phonenumber', 't1.timesubscribed', 't2.category')->latest('t1.created_at')->paginate(7);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and ended up writting a laravel extension to handle it. You can install it using composer, then it just works!

https://packagist.org/packages/datajoe/postgresql-distinct-on

This is what it would look like in your case:

```
Subscribers::
   ->join('subscriber_categories', 'subscribers.id', '=', 'subscriber_categories.subscriber_id')
   ->distinctOn('subscribers.id')
   ->latest('subscribers.id', subscriber_categories.created_at)
   ->paginate(7);
```